# Node titles as menu items in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

i've a node type "Gallery" and a menu title "Gallery" which shows all the available galleries with the help  of views.

Now, when the user creates a new gallery, i want the name(**title**) of that gallery to add as a child element to the "Gallery" menu item..

is there any module for that?

thankx..

Comment: Do you have a "menu" version of the view(s) you made to show the galleries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module [Auto Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/automenu). Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... automatically generates menu entries on node creation/edition. Parent menu item can be specified on a per content type basis.
>
> This module acts when the menu section of a node is left empty only. So, users can still organize menus manually. Moreover, default setting for content types is to not create menu items automatically.